# Read specific column of data from multi-line tab delimited richtextbox text in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, csv

I'm looking to be able to select multiple 'columns' of data from one richtextbox (called ReportText) and display it within a second richtextbox (called UploadText). By columns, I mean each piece of data that is separated by vbTab.

My data looks a little bit like this:

*column1 (vbTab) column2 (vbTab) column3 (vbTab) column4 (vbTab) column5 ..... (vbCrLf)
1a (vbTab) 1b (vbTab) 1c (vbTab) 1d (vbTab) 1e (vbTab).... (vbCrLf)
2a (vbTab) 2b (vbTab) 2c (vbTab) 2d (vbTab) 2e (vbTab).... (vbCrLf)*

--NB I have written in (vbTab) to represent the tab delimited nature of the information and (vbCrLf) for the new line.

--Please also note that the information in the first RTB would have more than 5 columns and 3 lines, above is for illustatrive purposes.

Could anyone please give me guidance as to how I would do this? Happy to elaborate on any parts where anything is not clear. I'm assuming I'd look to split in to 2d arrays (or similar) but not sure how to do that, nor call for the specific data from say column1 and column3 of the first RTB (ReportText) to display in the second RTB (UploadText).

Thanks in advance for your help,

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Lines` property of the `RichTextBox` takes care of the `vbCrLf` issue. In each line, you can rely on `Split` by accounting for `vbTab` as the splitting character. The sample code below takes the third column (index = 2) values for all the rows from `InRTB` and writes them, one per line, to `OutRTB`:

```
Dim rowNo As Integer = -1
For Each line As String In inRTB.Lines
    If (line IsNot Nothing) Then
        rowNo = rowNo + 1
        Dim colNo As Integer = -1
        Dim vals() As String = line.Split(Convert.ToChar(vbTab))
        For Each val As String In vals
            colNo = colNo + 1
            If (colNo = 2) Then
                OutRTB.Text = OutRTB.Text & val & Environment.NewLine
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this however brings back every bit of data, one by one in a message box - what I'm after is something that takes column 3 from each row and displays all results in a separate multi-line RTB so that I can see all data in column 3 of the original RTB. How could the above me ammended to help?

Comment: @Max I was showing you just the way though. You should be the one adapting the code you specific needs (actually it is pretty clear already). I will perform the modification but well...

Comment: @Max yeah... and asking for getting everything exactly as you need it is not the best way to learn (but doing something by your own). Don't get used to this kind of behaviour, here in SO (at least, not from me). I have updated my answer with a new code which delivers exactly what you want: bear in mind that the indices start from zero and thus the target column is 2.

Comment: this is exactly what I was after and I very much appreciate you coming back to me on this. After your first comment I started working on an If statement and can now see exactly how it's done!! You're certainly a big help, and you're advice is right about learning rather than being told - this will help me to start learning about If statements as well as splitting data :-)

Comment: @Max I am really happy to read that. Keep up the learning and the work-by-your-own